# Erro ao enviar formulario

Tags: php, javascript, html

Pessoas fiz um formulário com JS porem ao enviar ele só cai na condição de erro e não sei porque segue o print do console e os códigos.

OBS: o artuivo contact.php esta na pasta public html vocês podem acessar o site nesse [link](http://torreforteetiquetas.com.br/)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

essa e a linha de código onde meu formulário cai quando clico em enviar

```
$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Ocorreu um erro tente novamente'));
        die($output);
```

o HTML:

```
<form id="form-elements" onSubmit="return false">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 center">
            <div id="result"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" name="name" id="name" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" id="email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" name="phone" id="phone" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <textarea id="input" class="form-control" rows="7" required="required" placeholder="Mensagem" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default buttons" id="submit_btn">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

o JS:

```
//Contact Us
$("#submit_btn").click(function() {
    //get input field values
    var user_name = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var user_email = $('input[name=email]').val();
    var user_telephone = $('input[name=phone]').val();
    var user_message = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    //simple validation at client's end
    var post_data, output;
    var proceed = true;
    if (user_name == "") {
        proceed = false;
    }
    if (user_email == "") {
        proceed = false;
    }
    if (user_message == "") {
        proceed = false;
    }

    //everything looks good! proceed...
    if (proceed) {
        //data to be sent to server
        post_data = {
            'userName': user_name,
            'userEmail': user_email,
            'userTelephone': user_telephone,
            'userMessage': user_message
        };

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('contact.php', post_data, function(response) {

            //load json data from server and output message
            if (response.type == 'error') {
                output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">' + response.text + '</div>';
            } else {
                output = '<div class="alert-success" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">' + response.text + '</div>';

                //reset values in all input fields
                $('#form-elements input').val('');
                $('#form-elements textarea').val('');
            }

            $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');

    }
});

//reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
$("#form-elements input, #form-elements textarea").keyup(function() {
    $("#result").slideUp();
});
```

o PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = "felipe@agenciafront.com.br"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Torre Forte - Novo contato do site'; //Subject line for emails


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    }

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Os campos de entrada estão vazios!  '));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone = $_POST["userTelephone"];
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<3) // If length is less than 3 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'O campo nome não pode ficar vazio'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor ultilize um e-mail válido'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor insira uma mensagem'));
        die($output);
    }


    $message_Body = "<strong>Name: </strong>". $user_Name ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Email: </strong>". $user_Email ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Phone: </strong>". $user_Phone ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Message: </strong>". $user_Message ."<br>";



    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";



    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(). "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8';



    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $message_Body, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Ocorreu um erro tente novamente'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Olá '. $user_Name .' Obrigado pelo seu contato retornaremos em breve.'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `onsubmit ="return false"` é isso mesmo ?

Comment: @MagicHat o correto seria estar true?

Comment: Olha, onsubmit é um evento que ocorre quando o form é submetido, dessa forma que está não parece ter sentido, pois geralmente se tem uma função que roda com o form e se falhar retorna falso se não verdadeiro...

Answer (score 1):

Tenta verificar essa parte do envio de e-mail, eu posso estar enganado mas seu código aparenta funcionar:

```
$sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $message_Body, $headers);

if(!$sentMail)
{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Ocorreu um erro tente novamente'));
    die($output);
}else{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Olá '. $user_Name .' Obrigado pelo seu contato retornaremos em breve.'));
    die($output);
}
```

Acredito que possa ser na hora de enviar esse @mail está retornando algum erro, verifica se está tudo configurado para poder enviar o email, ou tenta fazer um teste sem essa condição para ver se o erro é nessa parte mesmo.